# String literal prefix not compiling

Tags: c++, string

A book I'm reading ("C++ Crash Course" by Josh Lospinoso) gives a snippet of code:

```cpp
char16_t chinese[] = u"\u4e66\u4e2d\u81ea\u6709\u9ec4\u91d1\u5c4b";
```

However, this doesn't even compile for me. It references *use of undeclared identifier 'u'*, so why doesn't it compile like the book?

Comment: Unicode literal prefix is feature supported starting from c++11. You need to enable it with `-std=c++11`

Comment: You are asking two completely unrelated questions. Delete the second question and post it separately.

Comment: @mvp Perhaps just upgrade. A compiler that needs a command line switch to enable C++11 is too old.